# Seeking a vim function to insert the text behind a hyperlink

Tags: html, vim, wget

I'm writing a book. I have a large notes file, with hyperlinks of interest. I'd like to be able to move the cursor over a hyperlink, execute a command, and have the text of the webpage inserted for reading, cutting, and modifying. Ideally, it would only be the readable text rather than the full HTML, but I'll take what I can get (or what I can wget, if that's the right shell function).

Surely such a thing has already been put together, but searches for "vim insert text hyperlink" and such are not very helpful. Have you seen this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your mouse cursor on a hyperlink, execute

> `:r`<kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will insert the raw contents on the following line.
To preprocess:

> `:r !links -dump`<kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Of course, you can map this to a key:

```
:nnoremap <F6> :r !links -dump <C-r><C-a><CR>
```

---

#### Various notes:

If you have quoted urls, you might not be happy about <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd> because the quotes will get included. Consider doing

```
:se iskeyword+=/,:,.
```

And use <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd> instead. Alternatively,

```
:se isfname-="
```

allows you to use <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> instead.

If you don't want to tinker with any of your settings, consider creating a function that saves and restores the value of `&iskeyword` or `&isfname`. To bring out the big gun, write a regex for URLs and use that:

```
func! ReadFromUrl()
    let url = substitute(getline('.'), '\c\v^.*((https?|ftp|file)://[a-z0-9.:/%+()]+).*$', '\1', '')
    exec 'r! links -dump "' . url . '"'
endf

command! ReadFromUrl call ReadFromUrl()
nnoremap! <F6> ReadFromUrl<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the cursor to the hype-link, and type this command:

```
:exec 'r!wget -q -O- ' getline('.') ' | html2text'
```

It'll append the content of the hype-link after the hype-link.
To make this command work, you need install `html2text`.
Good luck!